# Laravel validation rules custom message with second level of array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules

Here my code :

```
$rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'unit' => 'required|in:piece,kg,m',
        'price_type' =>'required|string',
        'service' => [
            'string',
            'required',
            Rule::in($services_ids->all()),
        ],
        'facility' => [
            'string',
            'required',
            Rule::in($facilities_ids->all()),
        ],
        'conciergeries' => [
            'array',
            'required',
            Rule::in($conciergeries_ids->all()),
        ],
    ];

    $custom_messages = [
        'required' => 'Vous devez sélectionner un(e) :attribute.'
    ];

    $validated = request()->validate($rules, $custom_messages);
```

The problem is that my custom_messages only works with 'name', 'price', 'unit', 'price_type' but not with 'service', 'facility' and 'conciergeries'.

Questions :

- How to apply my custom messages with 'service', 'facility' and 'conciergeries' too ?
- How to create a custom message for specifically one field ?

Thank's !

Comment: You can create your own rule see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify for which field you want to change the message

Try it like:-

```
$custom_messages = [
    'service.required' => 'Your custom message for required service',
    'service.string' => 'Your custom message of service should be string',];
```

And same process for facility and conciergeries.

Comment: Thank's it's okay now for 'service' and 'facility', but i don't see the error message with 'conciergeries', i think it's because it require an array field, do you have an idea to see the error message ?

Comment: Oh the message of conciergeries error is not display because of my blade view, sorry